# regex match contents of xml like content

Tags: regex, string

I have a string like

```
some stuff TOTAL_SCORE<518>some stuff <after>
```

The following regex: `/TOTAL_SCORE<\d{3}>/` will return

```
TOTAL_SCORE<518>
```

How can I have it instead return only the `518`?

## edit

I probably should point out that the string is a bit more complex and contains multiple similar fields like

```
some stuff TOTAL_SCORE<518>some stuff OTHER_VALUE<456> foo <after>
```

Comment: Just use capturing group around the `\d{3}` subpattern, `/TOTAL_SCORE<(\d{3})>/` and get Group 1 contents. What is the programming language?

Comment: Oracle SQL is the language. Please see the edit. The string contains multiple such groups. TOTAL_SCORE is not necessarily the first group.

Comment: Then what I said applies here, too. Oracle 11g+?

Comment: Yes. In fact 11g should be the version we are running.

Comment: Expected result does not change, I still only want to get the 518 from my field named `TOTAL_SCORE`.

Comment: Try `regexp_substr('some stuff TOTAL_SCORE<518>some stuff OTHER_VALUE<456> foo <after>', 'TOTAL_SCORE<(\d{3})>', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Comment: Add parentheses to what you already have, the parentheses are a capturing group that you can use to extract the part of the string you are interested in. Try /TOTAL_SCORE<(\d{3})>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
select regexp_substr('some stuff TOTAL_SCORE<518>some stuff OTHER_VALUE<456> foo <after>', 'TOTAL_SCORE<(\d{3})>', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual
```

The `(...)` capturing group will put a part of the match into a memory buffer with ID=1, and you may access it with the last `regex_substr` argument (here, it is `1`). So, while `TOTAL_SCORE<(\d{3})>` matches `TOTAL_SCORE<518>`, the `518` can be accessed separately.

See more about [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).